# Rails STI and views reuse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, sti

I have an STI model and would like to reuse the base views for the derived model.
For example, If I have Teacher < Person I would like the Teacher's view to contain the person's view fields.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question...they're available by default. When using STI each derived model has access to all the fields from the base class. (any field on the table)

For example, when rendering a partial, you could simply pass the object as normal:

```
= render :partial => 'person', :object => @teacher
```

The code above can be done in several ways, but I'm just trying to illustrate.

Comment: Is there a way to control the layout when using this approach? When doing this I get the edit/delete links at the end of each item and I don't get a chance to add the derived fields (assuming I don't want to put them at the beginning)?

Comment: Sure. There are a couple of different ways to do this. I'm not a huge fan of view logic, but you could have an if statement that checks the kind of person it is: "if person.kind_of?(Teacher)"

Answer (score 0):

If you are having teachers and persons controller then you can render views(partials, templates) from persons inside teachers views.

**Examples**

You can write below lines inside teachers views

```
= render :partial => 'persons/<PARTIAL NAME>'

= render :template => 'persons/<TEMPLATE>'

= render :file => 'persons/new'
```

Answer (score 0):

`render` use the right partial so if you have the `_teacher.html.erb` and `_person.html.erb` partials you can `render` the person partial inside the teacher one and when you call `render` with an object the right partial will be rendered:

```
# @aldo is a Person, this will render _person.html.erb
render @aldo

# @mr_brown si a Teacher, this will render _teacher.html.erb
render @mr_brown
```

Because the teacher partial render the person one you have in that case both the information.

Comment: Is there a way to control the layout when using this approach? When doing this I get the edit/delete links at the end of each item and I don't get a chance to add the derived fields (assuming I don't want to put them at the beginning)?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand well what do you mean, do you have the two partials and render the person one in the teacher one, right? Are the person's field not shown?